# I cannot find the error of this mysql query

Tags: mysql

I exported (using phpmyadmin) all the tables in a database and tried to import them using the phpmyadmin of mine host.

I am always receiving the same info:

```
Erro
Comando SQL:


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jem8a_assets` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
) ;
Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 4
```

I dont understand what is the syntax error, cause I see none.

This is the begin of my script sql, exported by phpmyadmin. Could you please, help me?

```
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `saladenhav2`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `jem8a_ark_editor_inline_views`
--

CREATE TABLE `jem8a_ark_editor_inline_views` (
  `element` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `views` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]',
  `context` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `types` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]',
  `params` text NOT NULL,
  `parent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `jem8a_ark_editor_inline_views`
--

INSERT INTO `jem8a_ark_editor_inline_views` (`element`, `views`, `context`, `types`, `params`, `parent`) VALUES
('com_content', '["featured","article","category","categories"]', 'article', '["article","featured","category","blog"]', '{}', NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `jem8a_ark_editor_languages`
--

CREATE TABLE `jem8a_ark_editor_languages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `jem8a_ark_editor_plugins`
--

CREATE TABLE `jem8a_ark_editor_plugins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'command',
  `row` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `published` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `editable` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `checked_out` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `checked_out_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `iscore` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `acl` text,
  `params` text NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `jem8a_ark_editor_plugins`
--

INSERT INTO `jem8a_ark_editor_plugins` (`id`, `title`, `name`, `type`, `row`, `icon`, `published`, `editable`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `iscore`, `acl`, `params`, `parentid`) VALUES
(1, 'Scayt', 'scayt', 'plugin', 1, '-1872', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 82),
(2, '', 'sourcearea', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(3, 'Source', 'source', 'command', 1, '-1824', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 2),
(4, 'Preview', 'preview', 'plugin', 1, '-1632', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(5, 'Cut', 'cut', 'command', 1, '-312', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 60),
(6, 'Copy', 'copy', 'command', 1, '-264', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 60),
(7, 'Paste', 'paste', 'command', 1, '-360', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 60),
(8, 'PasteText', 'pastetext', 'plugin', 1, '-1536', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(9, 'Find', 'find', 'plugin', 1, '-528', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(10, 'Replace', 'replace', 'command', 1, '-552', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 9),
(11, 'SelectAll', 'selectall', 'command', 1, '-1728', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 61),
(12, 'RemoveFormat', 'removeformat', 'plugin', 1, '-1680', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(13, 'Bold', 'bold', 'command', 2, '-24', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 58),
(14, 'Italic', 'italic', 'command', 2, '-48', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 58),
(15, 'Strike', 'strike', 'command', 2, '-72', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 58),
(16, 'Subscript', 'subscript', 'command', 2, '-96', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 58),
(17, 'Superscript', 'superscript', 'command', 2, '-120', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 58),
(18, 'Underline', 'underline', 'command', 2, '-144', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 58),
(19, 'Smiley', 'smiley', 'plugin', 2, '-1056', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(20, 'Link', 'link', 'plugin', 4, 'link.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{"dialogtitle_switcher":"0","dialogtitle":"Default","height":"230","width":"350"}', NULL),
(21, 'Image', 'image', 'plugin', 2, '-936', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(22, 'Flash', 'flash', 'plugin', 2, '-576', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(23, 'SpecialChar', 'specialchar', 'plugin', 2, '-1848', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(24, 'PageBreak', 'pagebreak', 'plugin', 2, '-1488', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(25, 'SpellChecker', 'checkspell', 'command', 1, '-2016', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 82),
(26, '', 'tableresize', 'plugin', 2, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 82),
(27, '', 'tabletools', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 82),
(28, 'TextColor', 'textcolor', 'command', 3, '-408', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 62),
(29, 'BGColor', 'bgcolor', 'command', 3, '-384', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 62),
(30, 'Form', 'form', 'command', 1, '-648', 0, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 75),
(31, 'Radio', 'radio', 'command', 1, '-720', 0, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 75),
(32, 'TextField', 'textfield', 'command', 1, '-864', 0, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 75),
(33, 'Textarea', 'textarea', 'command', 1, '-816', 0, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 75),
(34, 'ShowBlocks', 'showblocks', 'plugin', 3, '-1776', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(35, 'Select', 'select', 'command', 1, '-768', 0, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 75),
(36, 'ImageButton', 'imagebutton', 'command', 1, '-696', 0, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 75),
(37, 'HiddenField', 'hiddenfield', 'command', 1, '-672', 0, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 75),
(38, 'Checkbox', 'checkbox', 'command', 1, '-624', 0, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 75),
(39, 'Button', 'formbutton', 'command', 1, '-600', 0, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 75),
(40, 'NumberedList', 'numberedlist', 'command', 2, '-1368', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 90),
(41, 'BulletedList', 'bulletedlist', 'command', 2, '-1320', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 90),
(42, 'Indent', 'indent', 'plugin', 2, '-984', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(43, 'Outdent', 'outdent', 'command', 2, '-1032', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 42),
(44, 'JustifyLeft', 'justifyleft', 'command', 2, '-1128', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 55),
(45, 'JustifyCenter', 'justifycenter', 'command', 2, '-1104', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 55),
(46, 'JustifyBlock', 'justifyblock', 'command', 2, '-1080', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 55),
(47, 'JustifyRight', 'justifyright', 'command', 2, '-1152', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 55),
(48, 'Blockquote', 'blockquote', 'plugin', 2, '-216', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(49, 'About', 'about', 'plugin', 3, '0', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(50, 'Maximize', 'maximize', 'plugin', 3, '-1392', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(51, '', 'div', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(52, 'CreateDiv', 'creatediv', 'command', 2, '-480', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 51),
(53, '', 'editdiv', 'command', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 51),
(54, '', 'removediv', 'command', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 51),
(55, '', 'justify', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(56, '', 'a11yhelp', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(58, '', 'basicstyles', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(59, 'Table', 'table', 'plugin', 2, '-1896', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(60, '', 'clipboard', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(61, '', 'selection', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(62, '', 'colorbutton', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(63, 'Unlink', 'unlink', 'command', 2, '-1272', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 20),
(64, 'Anchor', 'anchor', 'command', 2, '-1224', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 20),
(65, '', 'contextmenu', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(66, '', 'editingblock', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(67, '', 'elementspath', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(68, '', 'enterkey', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(69, '', 'entities', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(70, '', 'toolbar', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(71, '', 'filebrowser', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(72, 'Styles', 'stylescombo', 'plugin', 3, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(73, 'Font', 'font', 'plugin', 3, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(74, 'Format', 'format', 'plugin', 3, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(75, '', 'forms', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(76, 'Undo', 'undo', 'plugin', 1, '-1992', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(77, 'Redo', 'redo', 'command', 1, '-1944', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 76),
(78, 'Templates', 'templates', 'plugin', 1, '-456', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(79, 'PasteFromWord', 'pastefromword', 'plugin', 1, '-1584', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(80, 'HorizontalRule', 'horizontalrule', 'plugin', 2, '-888', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(81, 'Print', 'print', 'plugin', 1, '-1656', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(82, '', 'wsc', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(83, '', 'showborders', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(84, '', 'tab', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(85, '', 'resize', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(86, '', 'wysiwygarea', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(87, '', 'list', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(88, 'FontSize', 'fontsize', 'command', 3, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 73),
(89, '', 'bidi', 'plugin', 0, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(90, 'BidiLtr', 'bidiltr', 'command', 2, '-168', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 89),
(91, 'BidiRtl', 'bidirtl', 'command', 2, '-192', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', 89),
(92, 'Iframe', 'iframe', 'plugin', 2, '-912', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, NULL, '', NULL),
(93, '', 'xml', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(94, '', 'ajax', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(95, '', 'stylesoverride', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(96, '', 'autostylesheetparser', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(97, 'Imagemanager', 'imagemanager', 'plugin', 4, 'image.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(98, 'Document', 'document', 'plugin', 4, 'document.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(99, 'Savecontent', 'savecontent', 'plugin', 4, 'savecontent.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(100, 'Versions', 'versions', 'plugin', 4, 'versions.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(101, 'Treelink', 'treelink', 'plugin', 4, 'treelink.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(102, 'Pagebreak2', 'pagebreak2', 'plugin', 4, 'pagebreak2.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(103, 'Readmore', 'readmore', 'plugin', 4, 'readmore.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(104, 'Arkabout', 'arkabout', 'plugin', 4, 'arkabout.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(105, '', 'uiheader', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(106, '', 'arkmedia', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(107, '', 'tabledefinition', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(108, '', 'autosave', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(109, '', 'preloader', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(110, '', 'styles', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(111, '', 'quicktable', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(112, '', 'xmltemplates', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(113, '', 'toolbarswitcher', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(114, 'Close', 'close', 'plugin', 4, 'close.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(115, '', 'paragraphdataprocessor', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(116, 'Email', 'email', 'plugin', 4, 'email.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{"dialogtitle_switcher":"0","dialogtitle":"Default","height":"230","width":"350","emailProtection":""}', NULL),
(117, '', 'browsebrowser', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(118, '', 'browsepopup', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(119, '', 'video', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(120, '', 'audio', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(121, '', 'magicline', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(122, '', 'widget', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(123, '', 'lineutils', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(124, '', 'contentscss', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(125, '', 'notification', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(126, '', 'notificationaggregator', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(127, '', 'focusmanager', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(128, '', 'dndhandler', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(129, '', 'sefresourceprocessor', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(130, 'Arkmediabutton', 'arkmediabutton', 'plugin', 4, 'arkmediabutton.png', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL),
(131, '', 'corecss', 'plugin', 4, '', 1, 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, NULL, '{}', NULL);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `jem8a_ark_editor_toolbars`
--

CREATE TABLE `jem8a_ark_editor_toolbars` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `published` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `checked_out` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `checked_out_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `iscore` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `params` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `jem8a_ark_editor_toolbars`
--

INSERT INTO `jem8a_ark_editor_toolbars` (`id`, `title`, `name`, `published`, `checked_out`, `checked_out_time`, `iscore`, `params`) VALUES
(1, 'Back', 'back', 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, '{"show_new":"0","show_save":"0","components":[]}'),
(2, 'Front', 'front', 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, '{"show_versions":"0","show_new":"0","show_save":"0","show_undo":"0","show_redo":"0","show_find":"0","show_close":"0","show_source":"0","show_design":"0","show_maximum":"0","components":[]}'),
(3, 'Inline', 'inline', 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, '{"show_versions":"0","show_new":"0","show_save":"0","show_undo":"0","show_redo":"0","show_find":"0","show_close":"0","show_source":"0","show_design":"0","show_maximum":"0","components":[]}'),
(4, 'Title', 'title', 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, '{"show_versions":"0","show_new":"0","show_save":"0","show_undo":"0","show_redo":"0","show_find":"0","show_close":"0","show_source":"0","show_design":"0","show_maximum":"0","components":[]}'),
(5, 'Mobile', 'mobile', 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, '{"show_versions":"0","show_new":"0","show_save":"0","show_undo":"0","show_redo":"0","show_find":"0","show_close":"0","show_source":"0","show_design":"0","show_maximum":"0","components":[]}'),
(6, 'Image', 'image', 1, 0, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1, '{"show_versions":"0","show_new":"0","show_save":"0","show_undo":"0","show_redo":"0","show_find":"0","show_close":"0","show_source":"0","show_design":"0","show_maximum":"0","components":[]}');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `jem8a_assets`
--

CREATE TABLE `jem8a_assets` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
) ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `jem8a_assets`
--

INSERT INTO `jem8a_assets` (`id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rgt`, `level`, `name`, `title`, `rules`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 626, 0, 'root.1', 'Root Asset', '{"core.login.site":{"6":1,"2":1},"core.login.admin":{"6":1},"core.login.offline":[],"core.admin":
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
                                                 ^---
```

You specified there would be a comment, and didn't provide one so the `)` on the next line is unexpected.

Comment: You might also point out that `comment 'primary key'` should probably just be `primary key`.  I get this error on sqlfiddle leaving it as is: `there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Answer (score 0):

You must separate the comment word from '0' and try add a comment  `COMMENT 'my comment'`

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jem8a_assets` (
 `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary Key',
 `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  COMMENT 'my comment'
  ) ;
```

Comment: This still errors on sqlfiddle.  I don't use `comment` very often, so I wasn't sure without trying.  You can either remove it altogether or change it to something like `comment ''` (which doesn't add much value, but does run at least).

Comment: I have update the answer  ... seems the comment is empty

Answer (score 0):

You need set as primary key and comment cannot be empty, put something or just delete

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `jem8a_assets` (
`id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT  'Primary Key',
 `parent_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' COMMENT  'foo'
);
```